# App does not load on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am running my simplest Activity App in Emulator which I created in IntelliJ. I invoked Emulator from the IDEA IDE, it does show emulator in locked screen format. After unlocking I don't find icon of my application. Where am I doing wrong? or how can I run it manually on Emulator?

Emulator shows following message on Console:

```
Waiting for device.
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6/tools/emulator -avd myavd -netspeed full -netdelay none -wipe-data

emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: dlopen(lib64OpenglRender.dylib, 1): image not found
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Device connected: emulator-5554
```

Emulator Snapshot attached. As you see. I don't find my app here

[image]

Comment: upload a snapshot of what r u doing?

Comment: @SumitKandoi Original Question updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows:

- Go to cmd, `cd` into the folder containing the platform-tools.
- Then -> `adb install myapp.apk` . This command installs the app.

If you are using [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. Just grag and drop your apk into the emulator.

If the emulator is not in sync with the ADB,which is responsible for the connection. Just restart the ADB like:

- adb kill-server
- adb start-server

Comment: is it not `adb` to install on physical device? I am on MacosX and `adb` commands say no device attached

Comment: Did you try restarting...? And just a suggestion though, try geny motion or a device while developing apps, it saves you lot of time..

Comment: Yes it did not make any difference. Original Question updated.